# Laravel Mail Queue: change transport on fly

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, mail-queue

I'm trying to use different SMTP configuration for each user of my application. So, using Swift_SmtpTransport set a new transport instance, assign it to Swift_Mailer and then assign it to Laravel Mailer.

Below the full snippet:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($mailConfig['smtp_host'], $mailConfig['smtp_port'], 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername($mailConfig['smtp_user']);
$transport->setPassword($mailConfig['smtp_pass']);
$smtp = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
Mail::setSwiftMailer($smtp);
Mail::queue(....);
```

Messages are added to the queue but never dispatched. I guess that since the "real" send is asyncronous it uses default SMTP configuration, and not the transport set before Mail::queue().

So, the question is: how to change mail transport when using Mail::queue()?

Comment: Just to ask, do you have queue listener on? Because your code seems ok based on Swift Mailer Docs

Comment: @Froxz yes i'm using queue:work with --daemon flag. Supervisord is running without any errors.

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @Bogdan version 5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `Mail::queue`, try [creating a queue job class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes) that handles sending the email. That way the transport switching code will be executed when the job is processed.

The [Job Class Structure Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-class-structure) actually uses a mailing scenario as an example, which receives a `Mailer` instance that you can manipulate. Just use your code in the class's `handle` method:

```
public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($mailConfig['smtp_host'], $mailConfig['smtp_port'], 'ssl');
    $transport->setUsername($mailConfig['smtp_user']);
    $transport->setPassword($mailConfig['smtp_pass']);
    $smtp = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $mailer->setSwiftMailer($smtp);

    $mailer->send('viewname', ['data'], function ($m) {
        //
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. This seems to be the right solution, anyway I'm getting strange error "exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io". $mailConfig holds the right credentials, the same that works with native mail-queue.

Comment: nevermind, it was a configuration error. It seems that mailtrap.io does not support ssl, so in newInstance method i just removed the option.

Comment: Another question for completness: does $this->dispatch(new JobName($data)) accept only one argument, or I can supply any args declared in job class constructor?

Comment: Since you are passing an instance created using the `new` keyword, you're invoking the `JobName` constructor, so you need to pass all parameters required for the class to be instantiated.

Comment: @Bogdan It works for me in a multi tenant app. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Best way from notifications since Laravel 7 : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#customizing-the-mailer

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->mailer('postmark')
                ->line('...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a test where I need 300 different mailers (to fill Mailtrap Enterprise) so having 300 different configs was not good for me.
I am posting the simple solution I found looking at Illuminate\Mail\Mailer class

```php
$transport = Transport::fromDsn('smtp://user:pass@host:port');
Mail::setSymfonyTransport($transport);
Mail::to('to@email.com')
  ->send((new LaravelMail())
  ->subject('Subject')
);
```

Having this you can do some string manipulation to switch between transport configurations